# Scala, ZIO - how to return custom response in zio-http?

Tags: scala, zio, zio-http

do you know how I can return custom object as `zio-http` response? I created simple class:

```
final case class CustomerResponse(id: Int, name: String, age: Int)

object CustomerResponse {
      implicit val responseCodec: Codec[CustomerResponse] = deriveCodec[CustomerResponse]
    }
```

and now I would like to return this CustomerResponse as Http response object:

```
Http.collect[Request] { case Method.GET -> !! / "customer" => // Response.as CustomerResponse
```

I tried to use

```
Response.json(CustomerResponse(1, "a", 1))
```

but it didnt work.
Do you know how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.

I think you can use ZIO Json to accomplish this. I am using ZIO 2 which seems to mess some things up however

```scala
case class CustomerResponse(id: Int, name: String, age: Int)

object CustomerResponse {
  implicit val encoder: JsonEncoder[CustomerResponse] = DeriveJsonEncoder.gen[CustomerResponse]
}

object CustomerServer extends ZIOAppDefault {
  val app: HttpApp[Any, Nothing] = Http.collect[Request] {
    case Method.GET -> !! / "customer" => Response.text(CustomerResponse(1, "w33b", 99).toJson)

  }

  override val run = Server.start(8090, app)


}
```

Comment: I used zio-json in similar way and it also worked for me

Comment: Awesome! I hope zio-http gets better ZIO 2.0 support soon.

Comment: Id just correct the above response to use Response.json rather than Response.text, otherwise you will get an escaped json string.